# PHP Select with Both Parent and Sub

Tags: php, html-select

When I view my Dropdown select menu containing both the Parent Category and Sub Category it displays incorrectly with all the parent categorys inside the optgroup label like this:

```
**Cat1 Cat2 Cat3** 
 - Sub
 - Sub 
 - Sub
```

my intention is this:

```
**Cat**
 - Sub
**Cat**
 - Sub
```

And so on....

Any ideas what I need to do to achieve this to correctly display.

Here's the current code:

```html
<select name="DeleteSubCategory" class="form-control" data-style="btn-new">
 <optgroup label="
  <?php
  require('functions/connect.php');
         $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM category ORDER BY CategoryName ASC");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($CategoryID, $CategoryName);
  while ($stmt->fetch()){
  echo "$CategoryName";
  }
  $stmt->close();
  ?>">
  
  <?php
  require('functions/connect.php');
  $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT SubCategoryID, SubCategoryParentID, SubCategoryName FROM subcategory");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($SubCategoryID, $SubCategoryParentID, $SubCategoryName);
  while ($stmt->fetch()){
  echo "<option value='$SubCategoryID'>$SubCategoryName</option>";
  }
  $stmt->close();
  ?>
 </optgroup>     
</select>
```

After feedback below I have joined in my query which displays as required :)

```html
<?php
  require('functions/connect.php');
  $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT 
  category.CategoryID,
  category.CategoryName,
  subcategory.SubCategoryID, 
  subcategory.SubCategoryParentID,
  subcategory.SubCategoryName
  FROM category
  INNER JOIN subcategory ON category.CategoryID = subcategory.SubCategoryParentID");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($CategoryID, $CategoryName, $SubCategoryID, $SubCategoryParentID, $SubCategoryName);
  ?>
  <select name="DeleteSubCategory" class="form-control" data-style="btn-new">
 <?php
  while ($stmt->fetch()){
  ?>
 
 <optgroup label="<?php echo $CategoryName; ?>">
       <option value= "<?php echo $SubCategoryID; ?>"><?php echo $SubCategoryName; ?></option>
 </optgroup> 
  <?php
  }
  $stmt->close();
  ?> 
      </select>
```

Comment: I would really suggest decoupling your logic and html as much as possible: http://www.phptherightway.com/#templating

Comment: Great Thanks Joe, I have taken your comments on board :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting your loops would do the trick, but it is messy and is a headache to maintain. Is there a reason why you not using Join? If each category can have a sub, why not share an index ID and use join? It would make the formatting much easier.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Great Thanks Robert :)

I took your advice, I will show in my update. Cheers for that